# TypeScript infer generic class from argument

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have a generic class:

```
type ItemTemplateProps<T> = { children: (item:T, index:number) => ReactElement, onPress?: (item:T) => void, itemKey?:string }
export default class ItemTemplate<T> extends Component<ItemTemplateProps<T>>{

}
```

I'm trying to use it in JSX (`ContentGridCell` takes a prop `content` named `Content` in this case, and `c` passed to `onPress` is also the same class):

```
<ItemTemplate onPress={c => this.presentContent(c.id)}>
{
    item => <ContentGridCell content={item}/>
}
</ItemTemplate>
```

However, TypeScript doesn't infer the type in neither function:

[image]

It complains about parameter `c` being `unknown`.

When I specify my class explicitly, everything works:

```
<ItemTemplate<Content> onPress={c => this.presentContent(c.id)}>
{
    item => <ContentGridCell content={item}/>
}
</ItemTemplate>
```

But I don't want to specify `<Content>` explicitly; I want this type to be inferred. I don't understand why it isn't inferred automatically when I'm using it explicitly with a type. How can I do it? (I'm on TypeScript 3.7.2)

Comment: I'm not clear on where the type `Content` should come from. If you expect it to come from the fact that `item` is used in `content={item}` then you are out of luck. Typescript does not do inference of parameters based on usage in the function body (perf reasons is my understanding). TS needs to determine the type of `item` before it goes on to determine the type of the function so the assignment is not even considered when doing inference

Comment: I see, I though it was obvious and possible. Yup, I want that to be inferred directly from the usage within the function based on the passed parameters. I'm off with explicitly passing the type then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something as simple as making the other argument (index) be optional?